# Simplifying complex data cell locations into rows with excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a data set downloaded from a web database which have variable formatting. The goal is to get all of the data into rows so it can be sorted and potentially turned into a CSV-KMZ(KML) file. After un-merging the cells the data is formatted like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qN0uT.png).

The brute force solution I have found involves using *`='cell number'`* in the cells to the right ([Like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miIfN.png)) and then deleting all empty cells to consolidate all the data in the same row ([example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtVIi.png)).  From here I can just select and drag down to copy that cell array into lower cells. The problem arises when coming across Responsible Party entries with multiple sites, like in the first picture, as they throw off the spacing which involves a lot of copy and pasting to work around those.

Because this data set goes down to row 10,000 +, and there are likely going to be more sets like this, I am hoping some of the great talent here can think of another solution. 
Thank you to everyone who puts thought into this problem!

Comment: I would recommend writing a parser for this data instead of trying to parse it with Excel. You could write the parser in VBA to run it from Excel but that's not necessary. You should use whatever language you are more comfortable with. How are you getting the data from the web database? If you could import the data using Access, for example, Access could easily output to Excel.

Comment: The data is coming from the website in either HTML, plain text, or CSV. Unfortunately the last programming experience I had was C++ in high school and Access is PC only which I don't have easy access to at work.

Answer (score 1):

The pictured data layout example is the key to your success. It is **well-characterized** data. That means it follows a set pattern instead of being all over the place. And that means you can write simple, straightforward formulas to collect each piece of it.

When I read the lead-in befor eclicking, I thought I was to see data all over the place. For example, {City} might be in cell D3, E3, or F3, perhaps, and others similarly all over the place, or perhaps combined with {State}, and each record different:  not combined in some, six in a row with {City} in E3, then a couple in F3, that kind of thing.

You suffer NONE of that kind of flaw!

Your only difficulty is in the Site information consisting of perhaps several sites, rather than only one per record, period. But it is a minor complication solved with two things:

1) A judgment about just how many Sites are possible per record. You must be thinking about that already since you plan to lay out the results across a single row per RP so use that.
2) Use of the IF() function to test a particular piece of data which will tell you whether you are to extract Site information, or to start a new record.

The second one will seem off a bit since you will be deciding that in two places, so to speak, not just one.

Once decided, cells in the output row can have simpler formulas that test the deciding cell's content, and rippling down the row.

What do you do? First, I am assuming the bolded items have been added for clarity and do not need extracted. (If they do, do it the same way.) I am also planning a simple output that will have a row of data, then a series of "empty" rows and then another row of data, and so on. The idea at the end will be to Copy and Paste|Special|Values, then sort and delete the huge pile of "empty" rows at the end. One CAN get fancier, but that's not in the cards at 11:30pm...

To extract the main information, the "RP" data (I will use the idea of it starting in T2, and assume the "Party ID is the "RP#".), you need a bit of data to fix upon and then relate the positions looked at for the other pieces back to it. The "RP#" looks ideal for that. So cell T2 would have:

```
= C1
```

Now use OFFSET() to find all the rest of the RP data. But remember each line in the output has to see if it should collect data at all. So you need to wrap that in an IF() to see if the row gets data or does not:

```
= IF( C1 = "", "", C1)
```

This will fill T2 with some RP#. In T3 trhough T7, it will show "". Move on to U2. Enter the following formula:

```
= IF( C1="", "", OFFSET( C1, 0, 2 ) )
```

If C1 had an RP#, then you are finding th evalue of the cell 0 rows down and 2 colums to the right. If it did not, you get "" in U2 (and you will keep getting such for all the columns seeking the non-Site data).

Continue on. Just vary the two values (rows is the first, columns is the second) as needed to locate each  piece relative to C1. Thant handles all the non-Site data sought. (*Interesting to remember, and being used next, is that your offsets can be negative values so you can use OFFSET() to look left and up as well as right and down.*)

For cell AB2, enter an offset of +4 rows (so *down*) and -1 columns (so *left*). So the simple IF() test, then the offset. It seems impossible considering the data for there not to be a minimum of one Site for each RP, but if there might be none, add to the IF() test:

```
= IF( OR( C1="", OFFSET( C1, 4, -1 ) = "" ), "", OFFSET( C1, 4, -1 ) )
```

Moving right collecting Site data, return to the simple IF() test but use AB2 instead of C1. (If C1 was not an RP#, you have an "empty" AB2 so an "empty" AB2 means C1 was also "empty" so no need to test each time.) Collect all that Site's data just like you did with the RP data.

Now the crux of the issue:  Is there a second Site or the beginning of a new record? The cell, same column, but 7 rows down from this record's RP# is either a new RP# or blank. "Blank" can be tested for as done previously. Let's say AK2 is where the second Site's data should begin. Just test that cell for blank or not blank. If blank, then there is a second site and you locate its data the same as above. Use:

```
= IF( OR( C1="", OFFSET( C1, 7, 0 ) = "" ), "", OFFSET( C1, 7, -1 ) )
```

which gets the Site # if such exists, or a "". Same kind of formulas as for the first site, just changing the row offset (the column offsets will be the same). If there could be no Site information at all, modify that to also test AB2 for "" so that if it is "empty" the "" results will ripple rightward from here.

Do this for as many sets of Site data as you decided are possible. Plus maybe one or two more, eh?

Now the "other half" of the existence of Site data: we move to row 3 and cell T3. Copy all of row 2's cells down to, say, row 15. There will be a series of empty looking rows a C2, c3, etc. do not have RP#'s until C8 is reached. Then data appears again.

And since T8 will not be "", the row to the right of it will populate with data. Yay!

You might be thinking that Site cells to the right of real Site collections might get bizarre or confusing entries because they read down into the next record, or two, or four, for their data. But the FIRST check to see if there is a reason for them at all and result in "" for the (worried to be spurious) Site # and then that ripples rightward resulting in "" entries rather than reading what would be some other record's data. No worries.

Copy and paste down either all the rows of data you have, or as many as you cna work with (remembering you not only will make your machine keep track of all those formulas in those 10,000 rows, but do a copy and paste of their values at the same time). Let's say there are no concerns here, but if there are, it's something you have to manage in sets of 1,000 rows or whatever might work well for you.

Once all the calculating is done, Copy the output cells and Paste|Special|Values into... somewhere else, like a second Sheet. (At this point, if machine power is a concern, delete all the rows of formulas except the first couple.)

Being on a whole other sheet lets you do anything at all to the output without affecting those formula extraction cells or the source data.

Once on the second Sheet, you have only one more concern:  you will be sorting the output next. Sometimes one needs the original data order and it is NOT a sort order Excel will produce. If that is the case, Insert a column at the left and fill it however you like with a sequential number list. It just has to be "constants" not formulas so nothing changes due to formulas recalculating themselves after being sorted...

OK, time to get rid of all those "empty" rows and have just a tight set of data rows. Sort the data (AND the numbering column too, if you needed or wanted one). Do it low to high, like usual so the "empty" rows appear at the bottom. Find the first of those "empty" rows. Lots of ways to do it... scrolling, say... or perhaps first go to ANY empty row and put "zzzzzzzzzzzzz" in its first (leftmost) cell so it will sort to the end of the data which will make it the first row before all the "empty" rows. Once you get to the first cell of the first row of "empties", press Ctrl-Shift-End to highlight ALL thetrash you need to take out. Clear Contents with the Delete key.

Now your data rows are all together, there are no spurious not-really-empty rows to mess with your use of the data, and you are ready to go. Work on it, or Copy and Paste it to a final resting place maybe in some other spreadsheet, and go to town!

By the way, the construction is very easy and not time-consuming at all. Once done, it's done forever, as long as the data doesn't move about. It will you know, websites change, software gets upgraded and whole new columns shift things, but there are lots of easy ways around those problems as you slowly upgrade your initial work.

Once constructed, the data is read the instant it is loaded, then you just do one copy and paste, the sorting, the deleting (all just keypresses, a minute, literally, not hours), and you're done. I mention this because having been in your place and solving things with brute effort just as you bring up in the Quesiton, I believe you might find it hard to believe but HOURS of nasty, brutal slogging through such with errors that have to be undone by the ton, mouse slips, and so on, will now literally be one minute. Enjoy the life that no longer steals from you!

Comment: Thanks for the info! This really helped to get this moving in a productive direction. I sort of lost the thread of things in your post after the last formula but its gotten me a lot closer to figuring this out. Everything was working pretty well but after site #4 the equations get complicated because the ones above tend to pull info from the following responsible party. In either case I think this will work well because having more than 4 sites will likely be the outlier case rather than a common one.
Thanks again!